# Laravel get specific column from main and relation table by with function

Tags: laravel-8

I am having problem to fetch specific columns from main table and the relation table by `with` function.

Two table

```
product 
product_image
```

Product Class have relation code which is

```
public function productFeatureImage(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductImgModel','fk_tbl_product_id','id')->where('img_category', 'F');
}
```

My fetching code is

```
$products = ProductModel::with(['productFeatureImage'=>function($query){
        $query->select(['file_path', 'file_name']);
    }])->where('is_live',1)
    ->select(['product_name','slug'])
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
```

Results is

```
[
   {"product_name":"Test Product 2","slug":"test-product-2","product_feature_image":null},
   {"product_name":"Test Product 1","slug":"test-product-1","product_feature_image":null}
]
```

How could I get data in `product_feature_image` object. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be correct; but, I believe you do not have the 'f' category in your 'img category' column.

Comment: Great to chime in, I would suggest a comment is better form for this response, as it is not a standalone answer

Comment: Although I do agree with you, I am a new user and do not yet have enough reputation to comment on this response.